# How to get all near WIFI SSIDs in raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I know in Ubuntu we have `nmcli dev wifi` to see a list of near SSIDs. But this command seems not exist in raspbian. Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 3):

Googling "linux find nearby ssid" suggests

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep SSID`

Comment: Any idea why `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` gets a full list of neighboring SSIDs, but `iwlist wlan0 scan` gets only one?

Comment: From the man page on Raspian Buster: "Triggering scanning is a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results."

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep ESSID
```

will list all ssids in raspberry pi